# c++ stringstream not working properly when changing integer to string

Tags: c++, string, directory, stringstream

I am trying to make a function that will create folders for me and name them using a combination of numbers. Here is the code I made for the function:

```
void folderMaker(int xCount, int yCount)
{
  stringstream ssObject;
  string xString;
  string yString;

  for (int x = 0; x<xCount; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y<yCount; y++)
    {
      ssObject << x;
      xString = ssObject.str();


      ssObject << y;
      yString = ssObject.str();

      string nameAndLocation = "C:\\User\\DestinationFolder\\" + xString + "and" + yString;
      CreateDirectory (nameAndLocation.c_str(), NULL);

    }
  }
}
```

I want to make the two "for" loops give certain values to the x and y variables. From there I want to make the name of the new folder created with those two variables included in the name. For that reason I use the ssObject I created. The result is that I do in fact make the folders I want, however the names are not the names I wanted. For instance, if xCount = 3 and yCount = 1, I get the following folder names:

name of first folder: x0andy00

name of second folder: x001andy0010

name of third folder: x00102andy001020

Why am I getting those names (instead of x0andy0, x1andy0, and x2andy0 in the case of xCount = 3 and yCount = 1)? and how might I go about getting the proper result that I want?

Comment: Is it normal that you set two times xString and never yString ?

Comment: `ssObject` is never **cleared** .. also your code doesn't use the `ystring`

Comment: @DOOM my bad about reusing xString, that was a mistake when I was retyping the code here in stackoverflow. How do I go about clearing the ssObject DOOM?

Comment: But why creating 3 intermediary variables for formatting the fodler name, when you could do the whole formatting only with the stringstream ?

Comment: @Christophe I tried doing it with the string stream, however the code wouldn't let me make a string in the ssObject without first changing the x and y integer variables into strings. That is why I had to declare xString and yString. Am I correct to do so in that manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::ostringstream::str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/str/)

> ```
> (1) string str() const;
>
> (2) void str (const string& s);
> ```
>
> The first form (1) returns a string object with a copy of the current contents of the stream.
>
> The second form (2) sets s as the contents of the stream, **discarding any previous contents**.

To clean up the buffer, use the second overload as well:

```
xString = ssObject.str();
ssObject.str("");
//           ^^
```

Comment: that did the job, the ssObject.str("") was exactly what I needed xD! One day I wish to be as awesome as Piotr S.

Answer (score 2):

Because you keep pushing data to the **same stream**.

The easiest thing is to use a new stream for each conversion, preferably in a function:

```
std::string ToString(int number)
{
    std::ostringstream os; // new stream created
    os << number;
    return os.str();
}
```

Or if you have a C++11 compiler, just use `std::to_string`.

Comment: I see. Is there any code to clear the string stream object? I can't really change the code that much since some other code depends on it, and if there is a one line code to clean the stringstream object so it can be reused, that would be ideal for me

Comment: @CodeBlocks: See Piotr S.'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not construct the name from the scratch in you ssObject ?

```
  for (int x = 0; x<xCount; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y<yCount; y++) {
       stringstream ssObject;
       ssObject << "C:\\User\\DestinationFolder\\" << x << "and" << y;
       CreateDirectory (ssObject.str().c_str(), NULL);
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing that, the error appeard that I couldn't insert the x and y variables inside that third last line of code you have there since they are integers and not strings.

Comment: @CodeBlocks: That's impossible. You can pass ints to streams. Something else must have been wrong.

Comment: Missing #include ?  Did you use + instead of << ?

Comment: @ChristianHackl you are correct, I used the "+" sign instead of the "<<". that made all the difference

Comment: @Christophe Thanks christophe, your method did turn out to be the best

Answer (score 0):

**This should do the trick !!**

```
void folderMaker(int xCount, int yCount)
{
    std::stringstream ssObject;
    std::string xString;
    std::string yString;

    for (int x = 0; x<xCount; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y<yCount; y++)
        {
            ssObject << "x" << x;
            xString = ssObject.str();
            ssObject.str("");

            ssObject << "y" << y;
            yString = ssObject.str();
            ssObject.str("");

            std::string nameAndLocation =   "C:\\User\\DestinationFolder\\" 
                                          + xString
                                          + "and" + yString;
            CreateDirectory (nameAndLocation.c_str(), NULL);
            std::cout << nameAndLocation << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup it did! I got the same solution with the ssObject.str("") from Piotr S., I wish I could somehow put both of your answers as the best answers